# é possível fazer atribuição com inicializador de objeto mais curto?

Tags: c#

Existe alguma forma da terceira instância funcionar com atribução com subtração?

```
    private void btnGrasieli_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        /*Isto funciona
        Bbanco = new Banco();
        Bbanco.Valor = Bbanco.Valor - 50;*/

        /*Isto funciona
        Bbanco = new Banco();
        Bbanco.Valor -= 50;*/

        **/*Isto não funciona*/**
        Bbanco = new Banco() { Valor -= 50 }; 
        MessageBox.Show(Bbanco.Valor.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: E se você utilizar assim: `Banco Bbanco = new Banco { Valor -= 50 };`

Comment: Jà tentei também. :C

Comment: Veja aqui https://dotnetfiddle.net/LXxzhC

Answer (score 0):

Você não terminou de declarar a variável antes do **`;`**, pois a atribuição de operadores/valores literais não será valida.

Você pode fazer uma "Gambiarra" que organiza o código se estiver utilizando C#3.0+:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Banco Bbanco = new Banco; { Bbanco.Valor -= 50; }
    Console.WriteLine(Bbanco.Valor);
}
```

Isso não faz muito sentido, pois está criando um `Banco` cujo já há um valor literal para `Valor`. Eu creio que seja **0** de princípio, mas se está criando uma outra variável, por que não colocar o seu valor diretamente na mesma? Se quiser criar um banco com dívida de R$40,00 faça o seguinte:

```
Banco Bbanco = new Banco {Valor = -40};
```

Agora se você criar um banco à partir de outro banco, você poderá subtrair pelo mesmo valor de diversas maneiras:

```
Banco Bbanco = new Banco() {Valor = 125};
Banco Cbanco = new Banco() {Valor = Bbanco.Valor - 50};

Console.WriteLine("Bbanco = {0} Cbanco = {1}", Bbanco.Valor, Cbanco.Valor);

// Saídas:
// Bbanco = 125 Cbanco = 75
```

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HlYtb1).